# Edit the text in a simple list in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to edit the text of the list, after long click on the list item the item can be editable. I have made my own logic for this but that is not working. I want to edit a single item from the list. Please give me an example.

Answer (score 1):

The following link contains the sample edit listview http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/